# Error catching WPF button clicked

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, error-handling

I have a button on click action, how can I add a error catch and return a textbox if result is not found. If result is found the textbox will be searched results. I have the following codes.

```
var response = e.Result.getSearchCoordsResult;
var pagedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMap.Classes.Global.ResultSetPager<TestMap.Classes.Global.Place>>(response);
Classes.Global.searched = 1;

Results.ItemsSource = pagedResults.SearchResults;
if (!e.Result.ToString().Equals("error"))
{ 
     searchError.Text = "No Results Found";
}
else
{
     searchError.Text = "Search Result";
}
```

This code wont work, it just cause the system to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a try catch?

```
try
{
    var response = e.Result.getSearchCoordsResult;
    var pagedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMap.Classes.Global.ResultSetPager<TestMap.Classes.Global.Place>>(response);
    Classes.Global.searched = 1;

    Results.ItemsSource = pagedResults.SearchResults;

    searchError.Text = "Search Result";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    searchError.Text = "No Results Found";
}
```

Comment: Pleasure! You should try not to use try/catch in your code when possible... but with JSon.NET I'm not sure how to error catch without it (It might be possible, I've never tried). Good luck!